# How to upgrade Material UI component from v5.1.0 to v5.11.16

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Our project uses version 5.1.0 of the Material UI React component. What is the process of upgrading it to the latest version which is 5.11.16 at the time of this writing.

I tried replacing the version numbers in the below listed lines in the project's package.json file, but it didn't work.

```json
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.1.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.1.0",
```

I get the below error chunk in my Azure DevOps build pipeline, against `npm build` command.

```
[build:types] node_modules/@mui/base/TextareaAutosize/TextareaAutosize.d.ts(14,93): error TS2344: Type '"required" | "id" | "name" | "color" | "translate" | "value" | "hidden" | "dir" | "form" | "slot" | "style" | "title" | "accessKey" | "draggable" | "lang" | "className" | "prefix" | ... 253 more ... | "onResizeCapture"' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof TextareaAutosizeProps'.
[build:types]   Type '"nonce"' is not assignable to type 'keyof TextareaAutosizeProps'.
[build:types] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[build:types] npm ERR! errno 1
[build:types] npm ERR! @servcorp/smart-office-navigation@ build:types: `tsc`
[build:types] npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: What TypeScript version are you using? Try updating to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install` as below, so it updates the `package-lock.json` as well.

```
npm i @mui/icons-material@5.11.16
npm i @mui/material@5.11.16
```

Comment: tried that and am still getting a lot of errors of the `[build:*types] src/root/root.component.tsx(304,68): error TS2322: Type 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.` nature, in DevOps pipeline